# Is it possible to make p2p chat using javascript without server?

Tags: javascript, chat, p2p

Recently i've been choosen as backend lider for course on my studies. We are suppossed to write BE for chat app that will allow users to communicate p2p without any server code (i know it means that there's no BE, but my proffessor isn't technical person). I've asked him if it could use webrtc, but he didn't like the idea of using STUN and TURN servers. So my main question is, is this possible at all? We are talking about an app that will run in browser, not directly in OS. And if it is, what protocols/apis can we use to achieve that?

Comment: Is web services allowed? because you might use firebase etc...

Comment: No, the app shouldn't communicate with any web services. Completely p2p.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I get your question right, so here are some general informations:

WebRTC as a P2P API relies heavily on servers.

1. **"ICE"**: 
   To connect one Peer to the other Peer, the peers need to know their IP address to exchange data. They can "ask" their OS for the registered IP, but this will only yield 127.0.0.1 and their local Network IP. This works for connections on the same computer or between computers in the same local network, but it will fail for everything else. 
   The ICE Servers STUN and TURN are necessary, since your browser clients are behind your Routers Network Address Translation (NAT). STUN gets the NATs IP Address and Port and TURN forwards Packets as a known, public IP Address if STUN fails.
2. **"Signaling"**: 
   Let's assume, that your Peers know their own reachable IP-Addresses (- probably the NATs IP and Port by using STUN and maybe even TURN). Even **IF (!)** they know their reachable IP, they have to tell the other Peer that this IP is in fact, their IP and the IP to use to contact them. They also have to tell the other Peer some other technical information to make the transmission of data work. To use WebRTC, you need to have a WebSocket-Server (or a combination of Server-Sent-Events and HTTP Post Messages), which forward this information. 
   After everything is established (they know their respective IPs and Ports, technical information, etc.), you can then send data over WebRTCs DataChannels.



   **My Advice:**
   Do not use WebRTC for the given use case. If you do not want to use a Backend-Server, you have to search for **"serverless"** Web-Apps. P2P will always rely on some sort of server to start the connection. If you use a "serverless" architecture, someone else is hosting the server / chat service you want to use (also commonly referred as "cloud based"). If it is about hosting costs for a prototype app, you may have a look at heroku.com, aws.amazon.com, zeit.co, firebase.google.com or other hosting providers with free, limited (test) plans.